# How to give a path to a file in a package file?

Tags: scripting

[image]How do I fix the problem with zsolve in the picture? I do not know how to give the path to zsolve. [image]

Comment: It says [here](https://www3.risc.jku.at/research/combinat/software/math4ti2/index.html) that you should set the variable `zsolvecmd` to the path of the `4ti2` executable that you've installed separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I do not really know how to give the path of the 4ti2 executables. I tried giving the path to the executable file for zsolve. It is not working. It seems you have used the RaduRK program. So, I think you can help me. I am using Windows 10. The executable files are located in C:\cygwin64\home\HIRAK\software\4ti2\bin. I have updated the question with the screenshot of the executables of 4ti2.

Comment: What happens if you load the package and then execute ``` math4ti2`Private`zsolvecmd ``` `= "C:\cygwin64\home\HIRAK\software\4ti2\bin\4ti2-zsolve" `?

Comment: After updating the path, and running all codes, I see: "math4ti2`Private`" at the bottom of the package file. Then Testing the zsolve file, again, it shows the same error.

Comment: Syntax: Unknown string escape \c. Syntax: 3 octal digits are required after \ to construct an 8-bit character. are also appearing when I load the package in the .nb file.

Comment: Backslashes have to be escaped.  i.e., `"C:\\cygwin64\\home\\..."`.

Comment: If you select the executable in your file browser window and then copy-paste it into the notebook, it should give you a string corresponding to the full path.

Comment: Thank you all. Let us see if it works.

Comment: The problem of backslashes is solved. Syntax: Unknown string escape \c are gone now The problem for zsolve remains.